# Stuck on a stadium python code

Tags: python, class

Hi so I am a beginner in python and I am a little stuck on a problem I have for class and would like some guidance on this.
The problem for class is:Stadium Seating: There are three seating categories at an athletic stadium. For a baseball game, Class A seats cost $15 each, Class B seats cost $12 each, and Class C seats cost $9 each. Create a python program that allows the user to enter the number of tickets sold for each class. The program should be able to display the amount of income generated from each class of ticket sales and the total revenue generated.
Add input validation for number of tickets so that only numbers are allowed. Your program must not let the rest of the code run with invalid input.

now I got most of it to work but for some reason my income 2 and 3 are not multiplying the number of tickets for the price instead it's just writing the number of tickets that many times from the price.It seems to be only effecting the Class B and C

Here is my code

```
sales1=input("Enter number of tickets sold for Class A seats:")
#Validating sale
while not sales1.isnumeric():
    print("INVALID INPUT:Please enter a number:")

#Convert sales to a number
sales1 =int(sales1)

sales2=input("Enter number of tickets sold for Class B seats:")
#Validating sale
while not sales2.isnumeric():
    print("INVALID INPUT:Please enter a number:")

#Convert sales to a number
sales =int(sales2)

sales3=input("Enter number of tickets sold for Class C seats:")
#Validating sale
while not sales3.isnumeric():
    print("INVALID INPUT:Please enter a number:")

#Convert sales to a number
Sales2 =int(sales3)

#Income

income1 = int(sales1 * 15)
print("Sales for Class A:$" , end="")
print(income1)
income2 = int(sales2 * 12)
print("Sales for Class B:$" , end="")
print(income2)
income3 = int(sales3 * 9)
print("Sales for Class C:$" , end="")
print(income3)

#Total 

Total = int(income1 + income2 + income3)
print("Total revenue from ticket sales:$")
print (total)
```

my outcome just looks like this

Enter number of tickets sold for Class A seats:1
Enter number of tickets sold for Class B seats:1
Enter number of tickets sold for Class C seats:1
Sales for Class A:$15.
Sales for Class B:$111111111111
Sales for Class C:$111111111

Comment: You need to call `int(sales1) * 15` ... multiplying strings works in python, but it repeats the string, which is not what you are after.

Comment: off topic...but o dear god, what happens if they don't enter a valid integer?!... they dont get the option to re-enter.... it just keeps spamming invalid! (I may be wrong... havn't dealt with python in awhile...)

Answer (score 4):

```
sales =int(sales2)
Sales2 =int(sales3)
```

`sales` and `Sales2` are most likely not the variable names you wanted to use, considering you later do

```
income2 = int(sales2 * 12)
income3 = int(sales3 * 9)
```

as if `sales2` and `sales3` were integers. Most likely, you wanted to follow the pattern you set with `sales1`:

```
sales1 =int(sales1)
```

and use

```
sales2 = int(sales2)
sales3 = int(sales3)
```

Note that once you have numbers, you don't need to keep calling `int` on the result of every computation. This:

```
income1 = int(sales1 * 15)
```

can just be

```
income1 = sales1 * 15
```

While we're at it, here's your next bug. This part:

```
while not sales1.isnumeric():
    print("INVALID INPUT:Please enter a number:")
```

asks the user to fix their input, but it doesn't actually let the user do so. It just prints an infinite stream of messages pestering the user to do it. You need to call `input` to get a new number from the user. The same problem occurs with the other 3 input validation parts.